# docker compose port already allocated

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, port, portforwarding

I have three docker containers that all need access to postgres on port 5432. Running each independently I can pass `-p 5432:5432` but I can't run two or more at a time because they conflict.

I'm hoping to get around this issue with docker compose but I need direction on how to do that port mapping in the yml.

This is what I have, which is not working :

```
version: '2'

services:
  foo:
    image: mynamespace/foo
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  bar:
    image: mynamespace/bar
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  baz:
    image: mynamespace/baz
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open the port on every container. You only have to open it for your database container. Which results in something like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  foo:
    image: mynamespace/foo
  bar:
    image: mynamespace/bar
  baz:
    image: mynamespace/baz
```

Comment: Database is not on a container - it's running on my mac. I'm using the `docker.for.mac.localhost` hostname in the python as an environment variable when connecting with the postgresql client.

Comment: This thread is making me think I don't need to do any port mapping at all since I'm not using `localhost` ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little confused by your question, too. But I think that's true. Unless you are messing around with a non default docker network config. Foo bar... :)

Comment: Hilarious. Ya I think we went down this road because this wouldn't be mac only so I lost track of what I need on my local dev. Seems to work fine. Cheers!

Comment: `-p 5432:5432` is exposing port 5432 to your local environment. Meaning that if one image is using it another cannot use it... as you cannot have more than one service using a port number given one IP address.

What you can do is either keep the IP to your virtual env or explicitly assign IP addresses.